# Grouping layout by folders (Android)

Tags: android, layout, grouping, subdirectory

With the growth of the project in the folder layouts accumulated a large number of files with markup. This naturally causes some inconvenience.

Can they be grouped into subfolders in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps one by one:

1. Create **Directory** in folder `res` called "layouts".
2. Create **Resource Folder** in folder named layouts, lets say call it "main-activity"
3. Create **Directory** in folder named activity called "layout"
4. Move your files to this folder that makes most sense.
5. Repeat for all your files.

At last add this to your `build.gradle` which declares where all the resources are located at:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'apt_generated']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main.aidl', 'apt_generated']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layout/main-activity',
                            'src/main/res/layout/adapter',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Notice! `src/main/res/layouts` MUST be second last and `src/main/res` MUST be the last path**

Also, switch to `Project` perspective to work.

Comment: When I do this, the files that are inside the nested folder complain that the URI's for xlmns:android, tools, and app are not registered. But in the files that remain in the plain "layout" folder it does not complain

Answer (score 2):

You can use plugins for AS. For example https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/folding-plugin

Comment: This plugin doesn't seems to work with latest Android Studio 4.1.3